# Decoding JSON with varying key-value pair using Decodable

Tags: json, swift

I am attempting to parse JSON using Decodable that has the following structure and I am being thrown the error:

> does not confirm to protocol "Decodable"

The JSON structure looks as such:

```
{
    base = SGD;
    date = "2017-12-29";
    rates =     {
        AUD = "0.95769";
        BGN = "1.2205";
        THB = "24.414";
        TRY = "2.8372";
        USD = "0.74844";
        ZAR = "9.2393";
    };
}
```

Note that I have shrank the size of the JSON object for readability.

The trouble here is that the rates are all different key-value pairs which are unlike the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250462/swift-4-decoding-json-using-codable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549310/how-to-decode-a-nested-json-struct-with-swift-decodable-protocol). My code so far as such:

```
struct Fixer: Decodable {
    let base: String
    let date: String
    let rates: [AnyObject]
}

//at dataTasks
do {
     let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(Fixer.self, from: data)
     print(results.base)
} catch error as NSError {
     print(error?.localizedDescription)
}
```

It would be helpful if anyone could advice under such JSON structure with differing key-value pairs, how should one write the struct?

My reference: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY3bTxgxWss&t=18s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for key `rates` is a dictionary, not an array.

The most reasonable way is to decode the object to a dictionary

```
let rates: [String:String]
```

Alternatively create a struct `Rate` (for example with members `currency` and `value`) and write a custom initializer to map the dictionary (`key` -> `currency` and `value` -> `value`) to an array of `Rate`

Note: Consider that neither unspecified `AnyObject` nor `Any` can be used as a destination type.

Comment: Thanks! Simple and sweet! [String: String] works all fine.